# What do "quite amazing" and "ever got written" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I collected this excerpt from a SAT preparation book. While I was reading this sentence, I was confused as to how to understand the bolded portion.

> According to poet John Berryman, there were so many ways to ruin a
>   poem that it was **quite amazing** good ones 
>   ever got written

Does it mean that there were so many ways to ruin a poem though it was beautifully written? Could anyone help me to understand the whole sentence clearly?

Comment: John Berryman was very amazed that good poems exist, because mistakes are easy to make while writing a poem; i.e., it is difficult to write poetry well.

Comment: Just add (back) a 'that' after 'amazing' (the 'that' has been dropped)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *According to poet John Berryman, ...*
>   (= John Berryman said or wrote or mentioned that...)
>
> *... there were so many ways to ruin a poem*
>   (= It was so easy to ruin a poem -- because there were so many ways to ruin it)
>
> *... that it was quite amazing good ones ever got written.*
>   (= The fact that good ones (good poems) ever got written was quite amazing)

In other words, in his opinion, it's so easy to ruin a poem. As a result, we should have had much fewer good poems than we do have. The fact that we have some good poems is quite amazing.